# How to test a new Wildcard SSL Certificate?

Tags: certification

What are possible sources of problems when a new certificate is installed.

1. Different browsers accessing the site [ff/chrome/mobile iphone/ mobile android/etc]
2. I don't think this matters but what network you test it from?
3. ?

Other than #1 I am really not sure what else to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CA who signed the certificate ought to be in the browser's list of trusted CA's; otherwise, the browser may report a problem or even prevent you from reaching the site.

As I understand it, a wildcarded CA is wildcarded [relative to a subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate).  You should verify that it does in fact work with every applicable subdomain.  (You can do that by testing against each of those domains, or you can just crack open the certificate and check the wildcard.)

I do not believe that the network you test from should matter.

Comment: Yup that's what I ended up doing got a list of all subdomains and just wend down the list, not much else to try I guess.